# A medalha de Curioso com bug?

Tags: bug, status-intencional, medalhas

Se tem uma coisa que me incomoda é quando tem alguma coisa lá que não deveria ter, como se tivesse algo errado que não estaria certo.

Já faz um bom tempo que a medalha de curioso está desta forma (18/5) e eu não sei qual é o motivo. Talvez seja um bug, ou não, ou talvez eu não mereça. hehe. É igual na instalação do Windows, que na minha cabeça parece que quando chegar 100%, vai continuar para 101%, 102% (infinitamente).

> #### Curioso - 18/5
>
> Fazer uma pergunta bem recebida em 5 dias diferentes e manter um
> registro de pergunta positivo.

#### Screenshot

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe me explicar o motivo? Porque realmente eu fiquei CURIOSO porque isso ficou assim. Ou está faltando alguma informação que não sei o que é?

Comment: Tem um aviso na descrição da medalha na sua página que diz: [necessário histórico positivo de perguntas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTDpt.png). Não entendi o que isso quer dizer mas talvez seja uma pista...

Comment: @Math eu aqui achando que era um teste pra saber quanto tempo eu aguentava ver sem perguntar. Vou tentar seguir essa sua pista pra ver o que acontece.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Para ganhar a medalha você precisa de um histórico positivo de perguntas. Veja na imagem:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Histórico positivo de perguntas significa que do seu total de perguntas feitas deve-se ter ao menos metade delas abertas, não deletadas e com pontuação não negativa.

Para quem prefere fórmulas matemáticas:

```
(total de perguntas - perguntas negativas - fechadas - deletadas)/total de perguntas >= 0.5
```

Você no momento possui:

> Total de perguntas: 45
>   Perguntas negativas: 12
>   Perguntas fechadas: 2
>   Perguntas deletadas: 12

Uma pergunta que foi deletada e está negativa entra duas vezes na conta, se além disso ela está fechada entra três vezes na conta, por isso dos números acima.

Logo seu histórico de perguntas está com a taxa de `0,4222222...`

De acordo com esse tópico do metão: [Asking days badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234259/229289)

Comment: Oi Math, estava lendo esse mesmo tópico. Você sabe me dizer se "perguntas negativas" significa apenas perguntas com pontuação `< 0`? Eu quero dizer, perguntas com pontuação `>=0` mas que possuam votos negativos contam como "negativadas?"

Comment: Pelo que entendi para o "histórico positivo de perguntas" as que estiverem `>=0` já são consideradas positivas, já para o "pergunta bem recebida" deve ser `>0`

Comment: Que complexo! Na teoria está tudo bem bonito, mas na prática eu apanhei agora. Então quer dizer que mesmo se eu fizer 5 perguntas, cada uma contendo 25 de pontuação positiva (totaliza 1250 de reputação), porém uma dessas tiver -1 eu já não consigo essa medalha?! É isso?!

Comment: @seamusd o grande problema é que você tem 12 perguntas deletadas que nem você nem ninguém vê normalmente e elas pesam na sua conta, fora isso todas as 12 estão negativas e 2 estão fechadas, então olhando sem ver as deletadas parece que seu histórico tá bom quando na verdade não tá tanto assim. No seu exemplo, se você tiver 5 perguntas com pontuação `>=0` feitas em dias diferentes e tiver uma negativa você ainda consegue a medalha, pois seu histórico estaria com taxa de `5/6` ou `0,8333..` e teria as 5 perguntas se encaixando no critério da medalha.

Comment: @seamusd a propósito, você já está apto a receber a medalha de curioso aqui no meta, é só aguardar até que o script contabilize a sua pergunta de hoje que você a receberá. Já no site principal você precisa de mais 7 perguntas que não fiquem negativas, nem sejam fechadas nem deletadas, daí conseguirá ter o histórico de perguntas bom conforme o critério descrito na minha resposta.

Comment: @Math bom, eu achava que se uma pergunta fosse deletada, ela não contabilizaria, mas contribuiria para manter a comunidade limpa. Talvez eu não tenha lido todas as regras, caso elas estejam aqui já vou me dar conta de fazer isso. É muito bom conhecer mais sobre a comunidade, trocar ideias e compartilhar conhecimento. Obrigado pelo esclarecimento.

Comment: @seamusd também não fazia ideia disso até encontrar aquela pergunta do metão hoje. Valeu!